# Lightning page component visibility filter criteria

Tags: lightning-experience, home-page-component, visibility, lightning-app-builder

We are facing a component visibility limitation when setting up filter criteria. Only 10 filters can be applied per component. As a workaround, we are using the "contains" operator. No errors are encountered when saving the below formula. However, it seems that it is not being executed. What am I missing?

((1 AND (2 OR 3)) OR (10 AND (5 OR 6 OR 7 OR 8 OR 9) AND (2 OR 3)) OR (10 AND 4))

Answer (score 1):

You can do workaround for this -

> Create a formula (checkbox) field and put your conditions in that
> formula field and reference that field in the filter for component
> visibility.

By doing this you can bypass the limit of filters. I hope it will help you.

Comment: Without having to create a new custom field, can this formula logic be applied to the component visibility?

Comment: As per my knowledge, we can not use formulas directly in the filter conditions.

Comment: I would like respectfully to disagree with that statement. The 3 available options when controlling a component visibility are: "all filters are true", "any filters are true", "the filter logic is met". That 3rd option allows one to enter a formula

Comment: That is filter logic, you can only define logic for your filters in that field.

Comment: What if you want to use more than 10 conditions? In filter logic, you can only use AND & OR conditions. Formula and filter logic are different things.